# Proper permission code for database file and database directory

Tags: mysql, linux, database

So I created a login python app, app will add data to database file while user sign-up, and app will extract data from database while user login, on production server.

specifically, I want website users to

> 1. not able to see the database file and its directory
> 2. not able to download the database file if it can find the url.
> 3. able to add/extract content to/from it through web app (written in python flask)

**Thus, what permission code (such as 755,660) should I give to the database file and the directory where the database file is located?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I found 755 is very useful, or 766, if it's a php/asp file which is responsive.